# Forecasting Weekly Time-Series Data with Multiple Regressors

Tags: r, time-series, regression, arima, forecast

I'm wondering how I can adapt Rob Hyndman's use of fourier terms like in  [this blog post](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecasting-weekly-data/) to forecast weekly time series data with an additional regressor. Below is my attempt, but I get an error reading that `xreg is rank deficient`

```
library(forecast)
gascsv <- read.csv("https://robjhyndman.com/data/gasoline.csv", header=FALSE)[,1]
gas<- ts(gascsv[1:300], freq=365.25/7, start=1991+31/365.25)
#assume that gasreg is an additional regressor used to forecast gas
gasreg <- ts(gascsv[301:600], freq=365.25/7, start=1991+31/365.25)


bestfit <- list(aicc=Inf)
for(i in 1:25){
  for(j in 1:25){
    fit <- auto.arima(gas, xreg=cbind(fourier(gas, K=i),fourier(gasreg,K=j)), seasonal=FALSE)
    if(fit$aicc < bestfit$aicc){
      bestfit <- fit
      k <-i
      l <- j 
      }
    else break;
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Edit: After some additional digging around online, I've found some materials that seem helpful. [Another of Rob's blog posts](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tbats-with-regressors/) uses a set of Fourier terms as well as a dummy variable as regressors. [This post on kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/kailex/arima-with-fourier-terms) (see 3. ARIMA model) uses multiple Fourier terms in a way very similar to what I'm doing, although I still receive the `xreg is rank deficient` error. Could this be caused by `gasreg` being the same data as gas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fourier(gas, K=i)` and `fourier(gasreg,K=j)` produce the same fourier set- I believe that the results of `fourier()` only depend on the length of the time series, and not the content. The rank deficiency error was being caused by using the same regressor twice. I don't think I need to input the fourier series twice, and the code below seems to suffice.

```
bestfit <- list(aicc=Inf)
for(i in 1:25){
  for(j in 1:25){
    fit <- auto.arima(gas, xreg=cbind(fourier(gas, K=i),gasreg), seasonal=FALSE)
    if(fit$aicc < bestfit$aicc){
      bestfit <- fit
      k <-i
      }
    else break;
  }
}
```